# Prove that $a^n+b^n \equiv (a+b)^n \mod n$, if $n$ is prime and $a,b$ are integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

What is the best method to prove that if $n$ is prime and $a,b$ are integers $a^n+b^n \equiv (a+b)^n \mod n$, ?

Comment: What happens when you expand $(a+b)^n$ using the binomial theorem?

Comment: If you have already seen Fermat's Theorem, this is very quick. Have you?

Comment: Work out on simple example like $(1+x)^3 \mod 3$

Answer (score 6):

Hint: The [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) states that
$$
(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}
$$
where 
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$
Can you prove that $n$ divides $\binom{n}{k}$ for $1\leq k\leq n-1$? This is where $n$ being prime is needed.

Comment: You should say a bit more, e.g. you never used that $\,n\,$ is prime (which is crucial!)

Answer (score 2):

From Euler's theorem,we know that:

$$a^n \equiv a \pmod n$$
$$b^n \equiv b \pmod n$$
$$(a+b)^n \equiv a+b \pmod n$$

So,we conclude that:$$ (a+b)^n \equiv a^n+b^n \pmod n$$